# dll can't be found but it is there

Tags: dll

I have a W2K8 box running some automation software.

Once of the drivers that I need to load for it adds a dll into a sub-folder of the program (in Program Files (x86)).

When the program tries to load the driver it spits out an error that it can't find the file.  The location that it is looking for the file is correct and if I browse to that location the file is definaelty there.

Other drivers that use similar techniology (i.e. dll's in that same folder) are working fine, in that they find there dll and load up.

If I install the software on a XP/Win7/W2k3 OS it all works fine for the driver in question.

Is there something funky that the OS is doing that is not making the file visible to the program.  The account that the servive for this program is running under is an admin account, the same account that I am loggedin with on the console.

I am told that the drivers are all C++ based drivers if that makes any difference.

Thats for any leads

Mick

Answer (score 0):

Just off hand, it sounds like a permissions issue. That the application in question doesn't have access to the Program Files folder. Is this something you have checked? If not, I would start there.